# How do I access an attribute within a nested object in a loop using VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently having an error when trying to access a property within a nested object using a loop in my `vuejs` project. It's surprising as other similar nested objects work effectively but one.

```
<template>
   <div>

      <tr v-for="travel in travels" :key="travel.data.travel_request_id">
          <td> <router-link :to="'/expense/'+ travel.data.request_no +'/travel' "> {{ travel.data.request_no }} </router-link> </td>

          <td> {{ travel.data.summary.purpose}} </td>

          <td> {{ travel.data.user.surname }} {{ travel.data.user.first_name }} </td>
          <td> {{ travel.data.added_by.surname}} {{ travel.data.added_by.first_name }} </td>
          <td> {{ travel.data.created_at }} </td>
          <td> {{ travel.data.status }} </td>
      </tr>   

   </div>
</template>
```

The `travel.data.summary.purpose` is what throws the error even though it is exists within the travels object.

`{{ travel.data.summary }}` returns an object containing the attribute of purpose but I cannot access it. The error shown is

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'purpose' of null"
```

Please see [This link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRsE6.jpg) for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some items the field `summary` is null, so you should check its value before rendering the nested field `purpose` :

```
  <td v-if="travel.data.summary"> {{ travel.data.summary.purpose}} </td>
```